# Ubuntu Core vs. Arch Linux on ODROID-C0 development board

Tags: ubuntu-core, embedded-system

I have a Hardkernel ODROID-C0 development board. At the ODROID-C0 website it says that some of the operating systems that run on the ODROID-C0 are Ubuntu, Android, Arch Linux, Debian, and OpenELEC. I am starting a new embedded system project, and was trying to find an answer to my question:

What is the most lightweight Linux system that is tailored for embedded devices? I stumbled upon Arch Linux and Ubuntu Core (Snappy), but did not manage to find a clear answer to the difference between the two. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Generic linux questions should be asked on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Rinzwind thanks for heads up im new to ask ubuntu, will make sure I move my question there

Comment: Ubuntu Core is an entirely new way to think about the life of software on embedded devices. I suggest that you read up more on it at http://snapcraft.io/docs/core/. You will find a wealth of information and see all the benefits that Ubuntu Core brings to the game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu Core is a minimalistic version of Ubuntu designed to run on embedded devices, and it is the more lightweight OS. The minimum hardware systems requirements for Ubuntu Core are:

- Processor – 600MHz processor (ARMv7 or greater, or x86)
- System Memory – 128MB RAM
- Storage – 4GB flash/storage for factory reset and system rollback

A new release of Ubuntu Core is released every 2 years on even numbered years (2016, 2018, etc.). Ubuntu Core 18 is based on Ubuntu 18.04, and is supported by security and maintenance updates for 10 years until April, 2028.

```
               Processor              Memory    Disk space    Download webpage
Ubuntu Core    600MHz ARMv7 or x86    128MB       4GB         http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/vivid/daily-preinstalled/current/   
Arch Linux     i686, x86_64 or ARM    256MB     800MB         https://archlinuxarm.org/about/downloads
```

If you have an application that doesn't need more than a minimal operating system and power saving is very important, I recommend Ubuntu Core.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, so you are saying that archlinux should be out of consideration when comparing to core ?

Comment: Check if your device is supported at this website: [Downloads | Arch Linux ARM](https://archlinuxarm.org/about/downloads).

Comment: it is supported for both systems, but no one answers the question of which is best for my device.

Comment: Check the size of the Arch Linux file for your device and compare it with the size of the Ubuntu Core file at [Ubuntu Core Daily Build](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/vivid/daily-preinstalled/current/)

Comment: @ProllyGeek As we don't know your device we can't provide information tailored to it

Comment: @Dev Odroid C0 by hardkernel

Comment: Ah, small devices like that will easily accept Ubuntu Core or Arch Linux. You should be all set with those.